# Show that exist a unique $x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{A_{n}}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Show that if $A_{n}$ is a sequence of closed, not empty and bounded sets of a complete metric space $M$ and $\operatorname{diam}(A_{n})$ vanishes, then exist a unique $x \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}}{A_{n}}$.

I can show the $x$ is unique, but I don't have idea how I can show why it exist. I tried construct a cauchy sequence, but my attempts didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the condition $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$, let $x_n \in A_n$, let's show that the sequence $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since $\lim_n \operatorname{diam}(A_n) =0 $, 
for every $c>0$, there exists an integer $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that
 $\operatorname{diam}(A_n) < c$, for every $ n > m > N$, $x_n,x_m\in A_m$ implies that $d(x_n,x_m)\leq \operatorname{diam}(A_m) < c$. 
This implies that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Since $M$ is complete, $(x_n)$ converges.

Answer (score 0):

It's not true, take $M = \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $ A_{n} = cl({B(n, \frac{1}{2^{n}})})$, this show that the statement is false.